# How can I save the result of a MySql query into VB variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, select

I have a query that counts rows, so it only returns an integer.

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ..."
```

How can I store this integer into a variable so I can use it later?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select from mysql put into variable VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027925/select-from-mysql-put-into-variable-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

You use NuGet package mnaager to install Dapper, then you do:

```
Dim con = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING HERE!"
Dim sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM person WHERE lastname = @LN"
DIm count = New MySqlConnection(con).QuerySingle(sql, New With{.LN = "Smith"})
```

https://dapper-tutorial.net